# The page cannot be displayed. HTTP 403.2 - Forbidden: Read Access Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-403, iis-5

I have been looking all over the inet. But I cant find the solution that works.
For some unknown to me reason, the IIS I have at work (**IIS 5.1 on WinXP**) stopped working. Even, when I try to browse for Default Web Site, I get this:

[image: The page cannot be displayed]

Looks like it has nothing to do with ASP.NET, since Default Web Site contains asp code and static content, that I cannot browse either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
I am spending way too much time trying fix this already :(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any possibility security has changed? Can IIS read the index.html (or aspx) file ?

Comment: No, it cannot. Sure, it has something to do with security (HTTP 403.2 - Forbidden: Read Access Forbidden). Cant figure out how to fix this.

Comment: That's my only immediate idea, I've seen issues where somehow IIS loses read access to the folder /inetpub/www . You could try opening it up to read for all users. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. There's a stack exchange for server questions try asking here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Well... something screwed up probably... Reinstalling IIS helped.

Comment: haha, Well, when in doubt reinstall. Glad that fixed it.